# Synthetic/redundant Django migrations caused by sysdate dependent date validator

Tags: python, django, validation, datetime, model

I have a date field like the one below in a Django model, where I want the date to be in the future (or today, but not in the past).

```
foo = models.DateField('Foo', null=True,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(date.today())])
```

This works fine, validation happens as expected on forms, however, `makemigrations` creates a new migration every day it runs with that date, below is an example produced today:

```
field=models.DateField(null=True,
    validators=[django.core.validators.MinValueValidator(
        datetime.date(2018, 1, 26))]
```

How can I avoid this? Should I use a custom validator instead of `MinValueValidator` or add a `clean` method to the `Form` subclass instead like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908615/django-model-validate-date-and-datetime-ranges)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to avoid this.
You've got a couple of options.

- Write a custom validator.
- Write a clean_fieldname method in your forms.
- Write a pre_save signal on the model which makes sure the value is correct.